# IndexError: list index out of range in while loop

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I cant get to understand why i`m getting Index Error.

at `a = array1[item]`

```
    while item <= n:
        a = array1[item]
        t = mid - a
        l = h_f(t)
        ab += l
        if ab > k:
            item+=1
            break
        ae += h_f(t + 1) - 1
        item+=1
```

n - number of inputed values, item = 0

```
array1 = [2, 3, 4]
```

Any help?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  But you need to use `while item < n`, since arrays in python are 0 indexed.

Comment: As an adition to @chris response, when comparing to the size of the array, you can use `while item < len(array_name)`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions Just adding this here for downvoters of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An list with `n` elements has items in indexes `0` through `n-1`. I.e., your loop should stop before `n`, not at it. Replace `<=` with `<` and you should be OK:

```
while item < n:
   # Here -^
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start indexing from 0 so last index is 2.
While n can be 3 code can get out of bounds

```
while item < n:
```

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question at all?